# Using _id as creation/insertion date

Tags: mongodb

If I don't need precision more than the number of seconds since the Unix epoch, is there one or more advantages of keeping a date at which a document has been created/inserted in addition to the `_id`?

(Note that the `_id` already includes a timestamp - i.e. number of seconds since the Unix epoch - representing the date/time at which the document has been inserted.)

Especially, will a query with a criteria on creation/insertion date will perform well when only using the `_id`?

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to know unix time for the document, then _id would [suffice](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.getTimestamp/). However it would not provide you rich querying that ISODate() can provide like querying for date ranges, or day of the month.

Answer (score 0):

Eventhough it is enough. It makes the application less readable. And if you are going to query over the dates (like documents after a specific date.) then it will  be slower since in mongodb , BSON matching used when it comes to querying.